# Custom field default value - populate with other entries from same field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have created a custom module with extra fields on the product screen. I am trying to have the default value be a drop down with all of the entries already submitted to that field or the option to create a new entry (same as the default value when adding a product to a BOM).

```
class product_part_detail(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    _columns = {
    'x_mfrname1': fields.char('P/N'),
    }

    _defaults ={
    'x_mfrname1': get_default_name,
    }

def get_default_name(self):
    return "test"
```

I tried creating a many2one field that refers to a field in a different table but I keep getting an error when trying to install the module. Below is the updated code that I am having issues with. Thanks in advance!

```
class product_part_detail(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    _name = 'product.part.detail'

    _columns = {
    'x_mfrname1': fields.many2one('product.part.detail.fill', 'x_mfrname1id'),
    'x_mfrname2': fields.many2one('product.part.detail.fill', 'x_mfrname1id'),
}

class product_part_detail_fill(osv.osv):
    _name = 'product.part.detail.fill'

def _sel_func(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    obj = self.pool.get('product.part.detail')
    ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [])
    res = obj.read(cr, uid, ids, ['x_mfrname1', 'x_mfrname2'], context)
    res = [(r['x_mfrname1'], r['x_mfrname2']) for r in res]
    return res

_columns = {
    'x_mfrname1id': fields.one2many('product.part.detail', 'x_mfrname1', 'x_mfrname2', selection=_sel_func),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.  The idea of a drop down of the values they have previously entered requires a many2one field.  You would create another model and then make x_mfrname1 a many2one to that table.  As long as the user has create access on that table they will get a create option on the drop down to key new values.

One other item, as you are using the pre-8 API, the method signature of your default method should be:

```
def get_default_name(self, cr, uid, context=None):
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried creating a many2one relation but keeping getting an error when I install the module. I updated with my new code above. Any help is greatly appreciated, I am having issues deciphering the official odoo documentation.

Comment: @CoreyHuntley I found Odoo Development Essentials to be a great resource for getting started with Odoo.